# Buffer allocation exception in protege

Tags: sparql, protege

I am working on a large ontology through Protege (5.5.0). Whenever
I try to add the SPARQL Query tab to my viewport my ontology, it only gives a blank interface under the SPARQL query tab. And only what it says is the following lines.

***“An error occurred whilst creating the view
BufferAllocationException:
Not enough memory to allocate buffers to grow from 0 -> 32 element.”`***

I tried to increase the heap size in the JAVA control panel. Screenshot is given below.
But the problem is same as before.
[I increasaed the heap size as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gUcR.png)

Somewhere I found a solution to this problem by updating the owlApi RDF library but I didn't find this plugin in the list of plugins.
Can you please refer me to a solution?
It would be a great favour.

I tried to have a SPARQL query tab on Protege. There should be a proper entry field there but the whole window of SPARQL query is blank as follows.
[SPARQL query tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZV3R.png)

Answer (score 0):

The heap size should be changed in the Protege boot script - this would be a fine named run.sh or run.bat, depending on your OS. The change you show might not take effect, if Protege is running with a different VM than the one you set the parameter for.

OWLAPI is not a plugin for Protege, it's a library Protege relies on and it's shipped in the /bundles folder. To update to a newer build, you can download the maven artifact for owlapi osgidistribution and replace the file in the bundles folder with the new file. However, I don't believe it's related to the problem you describe.